# RegAsm error RA0000 Could not load file or assembly on Network Drive

Tags: regasm

I experience a problem using a batch file to call Regasm on framework 4 on a network drive.
It works correctly when the dll is on a local drive.

The message is Could not load file or assembly filename.dll or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported.

The problem is discussed 
[here  ad "Darrens Developer Diary"](http://darrendev.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/problems-with-net4-regasmexe-on-shared.html)

however editing the config as described does not help

I also tried the advice 
[here](http://iknown.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/regasm-error-ra0000-could-not-load-file.html)
which differs in the line

```
<loadFromRemoteSources="true"/>
```

with this I received a different error
"The system cannot execute the specified program"

The DLL used to use Framework 2, but I unregistered it using Framework 2 Regasm.

Here is the regasm.exe.config

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <requiredRuntime safemode="true" imageVersion="v4.0.30319" version="v4.0.30319"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku="client" />
</startup>
<runtime> 
    <loadfromremotesources enabled="true"> </loadfromremotesources>
</runtime> 
</configuration>
```

Here is the command in my batch file

```
Z:
cd foldername
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319/regasm /verbose /codebase /tlb: .\SBD.CommBridge.tlb .\SBD.ComBridge.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct line in regasm.exe.config is

```
 <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
```

the case matters

Comment: I have also had to do this on a local drive for Windows 2003 R2 Server